# Wild Animals Faction?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm doing a custom playthough of Skyrim, and I'm having a little set-up issue.

I would like to add my character to the faction containing wolves, so that they no longer attack me. Is this possible? If so, what is the faction/command I  need?

Comment: So you're attempting to make the wolf AI believe that you are a wolf? Or are you talking about the Companions?

Comment: Show the wolves who's the boss!

Comment: @Ben I'm trying to get the wolves (the in-game wolves, not the Companions) to stop attacking me. I assume they're some part of faction that I can add myself to. Making the AI ignore me would work too.

Comment: You could try permanently enchanting yourself with the effect of the [Kyne's Peace dragon shout](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Kyne%27s_Peace). This stops all creatures aside from Frost Trolls from attacking you. I don't know *how* you do that though, so will just float the idea rather than adding an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Factions_W#Wolf_Faction) page, the wolf faction id is 0003E691, and there is a fox faction with 0009A741.  Try `player.addfac 0003E691 1`.  It appears they have a built-in "Ally" status with other wolves, but I can't say I've tried this myself so let us know if it works.

EDIT:  According to comments, this method works.

Comment: Aaaand, it works. Wolves now ignore me! Thanks! Your command is a bit off though. `player.addfac 0003e691 1` worked for me.